# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF but can insert manually on db

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi i am experiencing this error.

`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF`

i have checked my db structure and can insert manually in the db. my code is

```
    public bool Save(SaveTeamAssignedVm data)
    {
        try
        {
                var newdata = _unitOfWork.TeamAssignedRepository.Add(new TeamAssigned()
                {
                    CreatedBy = data.CreatedBy,
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                    UpdatedBy = "",
                    DateUpdated = DateTime.Now,
                    IsActive = true
                });

                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

I have not been inserting any sort of data that will interrupt the identity column.

i even removed other data to check if other data is the error but no matter what i it still has the error. any idea on why?

Comment: It looks like your database is set to use an identify column for the PK but EF hasn't been configured for it. Check that you have the [ DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] above your PK property in your entity.

Comment: check filed with attribute Identity set to 0 or not